# Is there a general book of mathematics which treat (all together) logic, ZF set theory, abstract algebra, topology and mathematical analysis?

Tags: abstract-algebra, general-topology, analysis, logic, set-theory

Is there a general book of mathematics which starts from first order logic, treats set theory (in ZF setting) in which first order logic is used, then abstract algebra (in which set theory is heavily used), topology (at least point set topology) and finally mathematical analysis (in which all the previous concepts are used). In all these parts most important results should be covered.

In this way one can study mathematical analysis having solid foundations of mathematics? Am I dreaming or a book of this kind exists?

Comment: Hardly. Each one one these topics requires at least one book, if not more depending on where you set the limits. Abstract algebra, topology, and analysis are huge areas.

Comment: Sounds like an awful book.

Comment: It is not a dream to study analysis having solid knowledge of the foundations of mathematics, but you'd probably have to read different books, one for each subject.

Comment: Evan Chen's Infinitely Long Napkin, is the closest to what you seek (you can find it online pretty easily). Also, Princeton Companion to Mathematics is a dictionary of sorts. There's also "All the Math You Missed, but Need to Know for Graduate School", by Thomas A. Garrity.

Comment: Possibly [**Fundamentals of Abstract Analysis**](https://www.amazon.com/dp/0867202092) by Andrew Gleason (1966, 1991). However, it's probably not as comprehensive as you're looking for. It might help to give some thought to why you want all this in ONE book. If it's for notation and backward-citation purposes, then how are you going to deal with your later study of math when the "math tree" branches out MUCH more widely than it does at this level? And if you don't plan on studying much further, then what is your end goal?

Comment: Thanks I will look at all your references and then decide

Comment: Well Schechter's "Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations" as suggested in the accepted answer is more or less what I was looking for. I needed all this knowledge in one book because this would point out connections among various part of mathematics that otherwise would not be so clear. Moreover defining the necessary objects once (while in different books, treating diffferent subjects, these would be defined mutple times maybe with different definitions); having them all in one book helps also remember better the things learned.

Comment: If somebody has some other book similar to Schechter's Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations, please write here in the comments as these book are really precious in my mind (also Fundamentals of Abstract Analysis by Andrew Gleason is fine but at first sight  Schechter's seems more complete, and indeed it is almost 1000 pages)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check out Schechter's *Handbook of Analysis and its Foundations*, if you can find a copy. :)